# Isolate y in this equation: $\frac{y+1}{y-1} = e^{-2x} + C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to isolate $y$ in:
$$\frac{y+1}{y-1} = e^{-2x} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant

This is a simple thing that resulted from me trying to solve $\frac{d}{dx} = (y-1)  (y+1)$, but has me stumped. Thanks.

Comment: We want to solve $\frac{y+1}{y-1}=A$. Rewrite as $y+1=Ay-A$, then as $y(A-1)=A+1$, then, for $A\ne 1$, as $y=\frac{A+1}{A-1}$.

Comment: Try rewriting $(y+1)/(y-1)=1+2/(y-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

This just answers your question about how to isolate $y$. I do not go into solving the original differential equation. I have given the most basic approach for clarity. With a little practice the algebraic manipulation is much faster than appears here. I would rarely write down all these intermediate steps.

Multiply both sides by $y-1$ to get $$y+1=(y-1)(e^{-2x}+C)\ \ (1)$$
Expand the RHS to get $$y+1=ye^{-2x}+Cy-e^{-2x}-C\ \ (2)$$
Collect all terms with $y$ on the LHS and all others on the RHS to get $$y-ye^{-2x}-Cy=-e^{-2x}-C-1\ \ (3)$$
Since we have too many minus signs for clarity multiply both sides by -1 to get
$$-y+ye^{-2x}-Cy=+e^{-2x}+C+1\ \ (4)$$
Use the distributive law to factor the LHS $$y(-1+e^{-2x}-C)=e^{-2x}+C+1\ \ (5)$$
Divide both sides by $(-1+e^{-2x}-C)$ to get $$y=\frac{e^{-2x}+C+1}{e^{-2x}-C-1}\ \ (6)$$
Finally since $C$ is an arbitrary constant, you could put $C'=C+1$ to get $$y=\frac{e^{-2x}+C'}{e^{-2x}-C'}\ \ (7)$$

Comment: @BobMarley I am trying to do too many things at once! Yes, your solution is fine. But your supplementary question has disappeared! Maybe you solved it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Useful formula for ratio:
>
> $$ \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$$

Now 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{y+1}{y-1} &= \frac{e^{-2x}+C}{1} \\
  \frac{(y+1)+(y-1)}{(y+1)-(y-1)} &=
  \frac{e^{-2x}+C+1}{e^{-2x}+C-1} \\
  y &= \frac{e^{-2x}+C-1}{e^{-2x}+C-1}+\frac{2}{e^{-2x}+C-1} \\
    &= 1+\frac{2}{e^{-2x}+k}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$y+1=z(y-1)\iff(z-1)y=z+1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=e^{-2x}+C$$
$$1+\frac2{y-1}=e^{-2x}+C$$
$$y=1+\frac2{e^{-2x}+C'}=\frac{e^{-2x}+C''}{e^{-2x}+C'}$$

where $C'=C-1, C''=C+1$.